# ClassCastException when try to load more on listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to add a loading icon as a footerView in my listview.
But when I Scroll and append new data to listview
I get ClassCastException and my app is close

I get the exception in when LoadMoreXML class was execute

Can anyone help me?

This is my code

**Main Fragment**

```
public class LayoutActivity extends Fragment implements OnScrollListener{

    ListView listview;
    ListItemAdapter theAdapter;
    ListItemAdapter myExistingAdapter = null;
    String URL = "http://localhost/api/question/get_newest_except/0/0/5";
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    NodeList nodelist;
    ArrayList<ListItemObject> data;
    Integer counter=0;

    public LayoutActivity() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main, container,false);
        listview = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.list01);
        ProgressBar spinner = new ProgressBar(this.getActivity());
        listview.addFooterView(spinner);

        new DownloadXML().execute(URL);
        listview.setOnScrollListener(this);
        return rootview;
    }
    public class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        public DownloadXML() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            data = new ArrayList<ListItemObject>();
            ListItemObject itemData;

            try{
                for (int temp = 0; temp < nodelist.getLength(); temp++) {
                    Node nNode = nodelist.item(temp);
                    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                        itemData = new ListItemObject();

                        itemData.setId(getNode("pb__question__id",eElement));
                        itemData.setOwner(getNode("pb__question__consumer__id",eElement));
                        if(!getNode("pb__question__consumer__id",eElement).equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                            itemData.setName(getNode("pb__question__consumer__name",eElement));
                            itemData.setJob(getNode("pb__question__consumer__occupation", eElement));
                            itemData.setProfilePic(getNode("pb__question__consumer__pp",eElement));
                        }
                        itemData.setStatus(getNode("pb__question__title",eElement));
                        itemData.setExtras(getNode("pb__question__topic__name", eElement));
                        if(!getNode("att__pict",eElement).isEmpty()){
                            itemData.setImage(getNode("att__pict", eElement));
                        }

                        if(getNode("pb__question__type", eElement).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                            itemData.setOpini(getNode("pb__question__total__opini", eElement));
                        }else if(getNode("pb__question__type", eElement).equalsIgnoreCase("2") || getNode("pb__question__type", eElement).equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
                            itemData.setOpini(getNode("pb__question__total__polling", eElement));
                        }else if(getNode("pb__question__type", eElement).equalsIgnoreCase("4")){
                            itemData.setOpini(getNode("pb__question__total__rating", eElement));
                        }

                        itemData.setTipe(getNode("pb__question__type", eElement));
                        itemData.setIkuti(getNode("pb__question__total__follow", eElement));
                        itemData.setSebarkan(getNode("pb__question__total__share", eElement));

                        data.add(itemData);
                    }
                }
                theAdapter = new ListItemAdapter(LayoutActivity.this.getActivity(),data);
                listview.setAdapter(theAdapter);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Koneksi dengan server gagal" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... Url) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("pb__question");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public class LoadMoreXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
        ArrayList<ListItemObject> data;

        public LoadMoreXML() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            data = new ArrayList<ListItemObject>();
            ListItemObject itemData;
                for (int temp = 0; temp < nodelist.getLength(); temp++) {
                    Node nNode = nodelist.item(temp);
                    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                        itemData = new ListItemObject();

                        itemData.setId(getNode("pb__question__id",eElement));
                        itemData.setOwner(getNode("pb__question__consumer__id",eElement));
                        if(!getNode("pb__question__consumer__id",eElement).equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                            itemData.setName(getNode("pb__question__consumer__name",eElement));
                            itemData.setJob(getNode("pb__question__consumer__occupation", eElement));
                            itemData.setProfilePic(getNode("pb__question__consumer__pp",eElement));
                        }
                        itemData.setStatus(getNode("pb__question__title",eElement));
                        itemData.setExtras(getNode("pb__question__topic__name", eElement));
                        if(!getNode("att__pict",eElement).isEmpty()){
                            itemData.setImage(getNode("att__pict", eElement));
                        }

                        if(getNode("pb__question__type", eElement).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                            itemData.setOpini(getNode("pb__question__total__opini", eElement));
                        }else if(getNode("pb__question__type", eElement).equalsIgnoreCase("2") || getNode("pb__question__type", eElement).equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
                            itemData.setOpini(getNode("pb__question__total__polling", eElement));
                        }else if(getNode("pb__question__type", eElement).equalsIgnoreCase("4")){
                            itemData.setOpini(getNode("pb__question__total__rating", eElement));
                        }

                        itemData.setTipe(getNode("pb__question__type", eElement));
                        itemData.setIkuti(getNode("pb__question__total__follow", eElement));
                        itemData.setSebarkan(getNode("pb__question__total__share", eElement));

                        data.add(itemData);
                    }
                }

                myExistingAdapter = (ListItemAdapter) listview.getAdapter();
                myExistingAdapter.addItems(data);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... Url) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("pb__question");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    private static String getNode(String sTag, Element eElement) {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
        String result = "";
        if(nValue!=null){
            result = nValue.getNodeValue();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int threshold = 2;
        int count = listview.getCount();
        if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){

            if(listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count - threshold){
                counter+=5;
                new LoadMoreXML().execute("http://localhost/api/question/get_newest_except/0/"+counter+"/5");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error **Log**

[image]

Thank you

Comment: It gives error when I execute LoadMoreXML class on onPostExecute method

Comment: I asked line. not method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call listview.addFooterView, Android is creating an adapter for you that supports footers. Then later when you call setAdapter, Android doesn't replace the adapter it created, but it still keeps your ListItemAdapter around and delegates most adapter requests to that object. Then when you cast the ListView's adapter to your class, you crash because your adapter is actually inside the wrapper-adapter that supports footers. Does that make sense?

What you need to do is to create your ListItemAdapter in onCreateView, and attach it to your ListView right away. Note that as soon as you call addFooterView, the ListView's adapter is actually a different adapter, but yours is still inside the new one.

```
public class LayoutActivity extends Fragment implements OnScrollListener{
    ListItemAdapter theAdapter; // don't need myExistingAdapter any more

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main, container,false);
        listview = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.list01);

        // Create your adapter with no initial data
        theAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(LayoutActivity.this.getActivity(), null);
        listview.setAdapter(theAdapter);
```

Now in BOTH your tasks, just refer to the adapter directly, and add items to it:

```
public class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ...
        theAdapter.addItems(data);

public class LoadMoreXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ...
        theAdapter.addItems(data);
```

Comment: I have try do what you suggest.
but I got NullPointerException because of I pass null value to my adapter.
I need to pass ArrayList data that I get from my Asynctask class
That's why I call setAdapter inside DownloadXML class.

Comment: Solved!!!

Actually, I must create my adapter inside DownloadXML, because I need pass the data, but inside LoadMoreXML, I must change like what you suggest.

Thanks, it's works now :D